# Typescript / Cypress: How to use forEach loop through two Objects?

Tags: typescript, object, foreach, cypress, javascript-objects

I would like to implement a function and use in there a forEach to iterate through two objects.
I have to compare both values per iteration.

Example / Idea:

```
const id = {a:'A2', b: 'B1', c:'C3'};
const name = {maria:'Maria',josef:'Josef',moses:'Moses'};

Object.values(id, name).forEach((ID, NAME) => {
   cy.contains(ID);
   cy.contains(NAME);
});
```

If I use two forEach loopslike this:

```
Object.values(id).forEach((ID) => {
Object.values(name).forEach((NAME) => {
       cy.contains(ID);
       cy.contains(NAME);
    });
});
```

logically it doesn't iterate evenly.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: That's right. I have it adjusted. But my problem is not the object, but the forEach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you to all!

With your examples I solved my problem.

solution:

```
const names = Object.values(name);
Object.values(id).forEach((ID, index) => {
   cy.contains(ID);
   cy.contains(names[index]);
});
```

Comment: Independent loops are better, there's no need to merge them for these test commands (see T.J. Crowder's warning).

Answer (score 1):

`cy.contains(ID)` and `cy.contains(NAME)` search for independent elements - you can loop independently.

```js
Object.values(id).forEach((ID) => {
  cy.contains(ID);
})

Object.values(name).forEach((NAME) => {
  cy.contains(NAME);
})
```

**Unless** you want to check both id and name on the same element, in which case `cy.contains(...)` is too simple.

You can correlate values via the index

```js
Object.values(id).forEach((ID, index) => {

  const NAME = Object.values(name)[index]
  cy.contains(`#${ID}`, NAME);  // get element with id of ID and text of NAME
                                // e.g <div id="A2">Maria</div>

})
```

By the way, it's better to use plural form for lists and single form for list items, rather than lower case and upper case.

I kept your convention to make the change clearer, but consider `names` and `name`, `ids` and `id`.

Comment: Your second solution repeatedly builds new arrays of values for `name`, which seems less than ideal (though granted, it'll rarely matter).

Answer (score 0):

**Beware that relying on property order is asking for trouble.** Property order is **complex**. It depends on how the object was created and the names of the properties. For example, the properties in these two objects are in a **different** order. Some examples of that:

```js
// The properties in these objects are in a *different* order from one another
const ex1a = {x: 1, y: 2};
const ex1b = {y: 2, x: 1};
console.log(sameOrder(ex1a, ex1b)); // false

// Less obviously, the order of the properties in these two objects
// **is the same**:
const ex2a = {"2": 1, x: 2};
const ex2b = {x: 2, "2": 1};
console.log(sameOrder(ex2a, ex2b)); // true

// The order of these is the same:
const ex3a = {};
const ex3b = {a: 1, b: 2};
ex3a.a = 1;
ex3a.b = 2;
console.log(sameOrder(ex3a, ex3b)); // true

// But the order of these is different:
const ex4a = {};
const ex4b = {a: 1, b: 2};
ex4a.b = 2;
ex4a.a = 1;
console.log(sameOrder(ex4a, ex4b)); // false

// And so on.

function sameOrder(a, b) {
    const anames = Object.keys(a);
    const bnames = Object.keys(b);
    return anames.length === bnames.length &&
        anames.every((aname, index) => aname === bnames[index]);
}
```

But **if you don't care about the order** and only care about the values, just get the values as arrays and then use a simple loop:

```
const idValues = Object.values(id);
const nameValues = Object.values(name);
for (let i = 0, max = Math.max(idValues.length, nameValues.length); i < max; ++i) {
    const idValue = idValues[i];
    const nameValue = nameValues[i];
    // ...do something with `idValue` and `nameValue`...
    // Note that if the arrays aren't the same length, one of those will be `undefined`
    // once the loop has gone beyond the length of the array it came from.
}
```